# How to display custom image on AdMob?

Tags: android, admob

I just started learning Admob. I'd like to display my own image on the Admob banner.

Here's the code taken from [official doc](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/banner):

```
 <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111">
        </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

And this is my Admob page:
[image]

I don't see how you can upload/change the image. Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: You are looking at Admob as a publisher (place where ads go). You need to look at as a advertiser with a campaign (like: https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6177172?hl=en&ref_topic=6162738) If this isn't your question, please clarify.

Comment: what you are looking for is in-house ad campaign.. refer this link https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6212567?hl=en

Comment: OK I see. "AdMob campaign" is the keyword :)